# Empty titles in calendars while importing

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I have code like:

```
let calendars = EKEventStore().calendars(for: entityType)  

for calendar in calendars {  
    ...  
    createListFrom(calendar: calendar, entityType: entityType)  
}  

...  

newList.name = calendar.title
```

In iOS 10, `calendar.title` is real name, but in iOS 11 it is always `nil`.

Is it an iOS 11 bug or am I doing something wrong?

My Problem in  this line

```
let calendars = EKEventStore().calendars(for: entityType)
```

But it works that way

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
```

Answer (score 0):

For calendar use the below lines of code.

```
var calenders: [EKCalendar]?
let eventStore = EKEventStore();

func fetchCalendarEvents(){
 calenders = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
 for calendar in calenders!{
   print(calendar.title)
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you requested for permissions ?

Comment: Also other parts of api works correct in iOS 11 too. Getting other properties, calendar tasks, reminder tasks. Only calendar (lists) titles do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem that same code work in iOS 10 perfectly but in iOS 11 not work

the problem become from permission that you request from object and you try to get info from other

you must request for permission every time you need to init your calendar object and use this object to get your info

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: {
            (accessGranted: Bool, error: Error?) in

            if accessGranted == true {

                let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: entityType)  

                for calendar in calendars {  
                ...  
                createListFrom(calendar: calendar, entityType: entityType)  
                }  
            }
        }
```